# reledmac twocolumns critical notes

Tags: reledmac

In the MWE is shown the alignement of lines in two columns footnotes.
The alignement of familiar footnote is normal, i. e. at same level.
In critical footnote the first line of second column is lower of the corresponding first line in the first column.
Is it possible to both at same level?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xhsizetwocol[B]{0.485\hsize}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] \footnoteA{\lipsum[1]}\footnoteA{seconda nota}\footnoteA{terza nota}\footnoteA{quarta nota}
\beginnumbering
\pstart critical \edtext{footnote example}{\Bfootnote{\lipsum[3]}}\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is a bug in reledmac. I will correct right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in reledmac. The version 2.28.1, just send on CTAN, fix it.

So wait few days, and then update your TeXLIve/MikTeX distribution.